# Call method on nested service in typescript

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code not work? I am simply trying to call a method on a private service in my class, which depends on another service.

Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'typeof AnotherService'.

```
class Service {
    constructor() { }
}

class AnotherService {
    constructor(private service: Service) { }

    foo() {
        alert('bar!');
    }
}

class yetAnotherService {
    constructor(private service: typeof AnotherService) { }

    sayFoo() {
        this.service.foo();
    }
}

let myService = new yetAnotherService(AnotherService);
myService.sayFoo();
```

Comment: 1: What is the error you are getting? Just saying it "doesn't work" is not helpful. 2: In `yetAnotherService`, youre passing in the `AnotherService` constructor, not an instance. Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: see my edit please...

Comment: Try: `let myService = new yetAnotherService(new AnotherService(new Service()))` and remove the `typeof` from the `yetAnotherSerivce` constructor signature?

Comment: Wow, yes that worked but I figured there would be a cleaner way to write it! hmm